# TiddlyWiki 5 on MS SharePoint / Teams?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I have a TiddlyWiki instance that was build on v5.3.1, with no additional plugins or functional modifications, just content. I developed it on my Windows 10 desktop in Firefox on local or OneDrive shared disk where it appears normally. When I drop this file in my employer's MS Sharepoint/Teams workspace and access the file, it does not display as normal, but just shows a page like,

```
This TiddlyWiki contains the following tiddlers:

$:/config/EditorToolbarButtons/Visibility/$:/core/ui/EditorToolbar/heading-4
$:/config/NewJournal/Text
$:/config/NewJournal/Title
$:/config/NewTiddler/Tags
$:/config/PageControlButtons/Visibility/$:/core/ui/Buttons/advanced-search
$:/config/PageControlButtons/Visibility/$:/core/ui/Buttons/close-all
$:/config/PageControlButtons/Visibility/$:/core/ui/Buttons/control-panel
[...]
```

I saw the suggestion at [TiddlyWiki.com](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Saving%20via%20WebDAV) that suggested renaming the file from .html to .aspx and tried the same. That file does not even display, but offers to download.

Can anyone suggest a way to get it to display properly? I am not so concerned with saving changes in that environment, though that would be nice.